# Spinner OnItemSelected firing unexpectedly causing UI problems

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I have an app that access the internet. It parses a page (like StackOverflow) with headlines and pages.

I have an AsyncTask that gets the headlines for those pages, and I have a hovering spinner on the bottom with the pages. The spinner has an OnItemSelectedListener that fires the AsyncTask with the page attached to it:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long arg3) {
                    Log.i("ONITEMSELECTED", "ClickedCount: " + clickedCount
                            + ", initCount: " + initCount);

                    if (initCount != clickedCount) {
                        clickedCount++;
                        Log.i("SELECTED", "Called");
                    } else {
                        initCount++;
                        String page = adapter2.getItem(position);
                        new ParseHTML()
                                .execute(
                                        "http://m.eksisozluk.com/index/today",
                                        page);
                        Log.i("SELECTED", "Page loading: " + page);
                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

As you can see, I tried counting the clicks and loads of the `onItemSelected`, but this causes to load the pages correctly, but it puts the `Spinner` to page 1, even if I have selected page 8.
How can I ensure this type of loading will work on my app?

Comment: I changed the spinner to a button with an `OnClickListener` that fires a `AlertDialog` and it works like it should. Thanks! But I still would like to know why the Spinner acts like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner1.setSelection(position);
```

use this in the onItemSelected

Comment: It gets set to 1, not 1 below. Can you elaborate why this should work?